# AngularJS - Angular UI-Router reload only nested view, not parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know this is rather long, but I need to provide some context before my main question. I am creating a page that will be split into two columns. Here is the ui-router code:

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/projects/edit")

  $stateProvider
    .state('projects', {
      url: "/projects",
      template: "<div ui-view></div>"
    })

    .state('projects.edit', {
      resolve: {
        test: function(){
          console.log('projects.edit resolve called')
        }
      },
      url: "/edit",
      templateUrl: "projects.html",
      controller: function($scope, $state){
        $state.go('projects.edit.surveys')

        $scope.transitionToOtherRoute = function () {
            $state.transitionTo('otherRoute')
        }
      }
    })
    .state('projects.edit.surveys', {
      resolve: {
        items: function(){
          var randomNumberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
          //this will just shuffle the array
          for(var j, x, i = randomNumberArray.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = randomNumberArray[--i], randomNumberArray[i] = randomNumberArray[j], randomNumberArray[j] = x);
          return randomNumberArray
        }
      },
      url: "/surveys",
      views: {
        "viewA": { 
            templateUrl: "projects.surveys.html",
            controller: function($scope, items, $state){
            $scope.items = items
            $scope.addSurvey = function(){
              $state.transitionTo($state.current, $state.params, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true })
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .state('otherRoute', {
      url: "/otherRoute",
      templateUrl:"otherRoute.html"
    })
```

Basically, the user will be transitioned to the `projects.edit` state, which has a template that looks like this:

```
<h3>PROJECTS.HTML PARTIAL</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Input Text: <input type="text"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateProject()">Go to otherRoute</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <a ui-sref=".surveys"></a>
    <div ui-view="viewA"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The user will be presented with two columns. The left column will just have an input field and button, which when pressed will transition the user to the `otherRoute` state.

When we transition to the `projects.edit` state, it's controller will call `$state.go('projects.edit.surveys')`, which will set up it's nested view in the right column. The `projects.edit.surveys` state will first resolve an array of numbers in a random order, which it will pass into the controller as a parameter called `items`. The `projects.surveys.html` partial will then be placed in the right column. It will show the list of numbers in a random order and have a button, which calls `$state.transitionTo($state.current, $state.params, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true })`. This button will reload the `projects.edit.surveys` state. The user will see the numbers in a different order, and any text in the input field in the left column will disappear.

This can be seen in action in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SK8hjMpw6kvPiTdVeEhz?p=preview

**This all leads to my question: how can I only reload the content of the right column ie the nested view (`projects.edit.surveys`), without reloading the parent view (`projects.edit`)?** I would like to be able press the button in the right column and only re-sort the numbers, which is done in `projects.edit.surveys` state's resolve, and not clear the input field in the left column (and not call the resolve methods in `projects.edit`). In other words, I'd like only refresh the right column `projects.edit.surveys` state, without affecting anything in the left hand `projects.edit` state.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pdu53I5uDvmkN1pZntli?p=preview) with one modification. Instead of using very extreme setting `reload: true`, we can profit from native `ui-router` desing:

> reload the state in case its declared param has changed

So, this would be the new state and controller definition:

```
.state('projects.edit.surveys', {
      resolve: {
        ... // unchanged
      },
      // here we declare param trigger
      url: "/surveys/{trigger}",
      views: { 
      '' : { 
            templateUrl: "projects.surveys.html",
            controller: function($scope, items, $state){
              $scope.items = items
              $scope.addSurvey = function(){

                // here we copy current params
                var params = angular.copy($state.params);
                // do some tricks to not change URL
                params.trigger = params.trigger === null ? "" : null;
                // go to the same state but without reload : true
                $state.transitionTo($state.current, params, { reload: false, inherit: true, notify: true })
              }
            }
        }
      }
    })
```

From a user perspective, param is changing but not its visibility - it is null or string.Empty ... Check that adjustment and *a bit more native `ui-router` solution* [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pdu53I5uDvmkN1pZntli?p=preview)

Comment: This seems to be no longer working with ui-router 0.2.13. New possible solution: `url: '/surveys?trigger'`, `var params = angular.extend({}, $state.params, { trigger: $state.params.trigger ? undefined : 'x' });`, `$state.go($state.current, params, { location: false });`. Works with ui-router 0.2.10  as well, [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BwXbhX2Gfu9ZHbhcatJX)