# Reload nested state only not parent with url parameter ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state and a nested state in my app.js file.  The parent state has a button that controls what is viewed in the nested state, this is done by setting url parameter and the nested state's controller figures out what to show.  I want to reload JUST the nested state when the user clicks the button.

I have both the parent state and the state I want to be reloading now on click.

I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165344/angularjs-angular-ui-router-reload-only-nested-view-not-parent) but the button being click is on the same page as the view being reloaded.

App.js file

```
.state('index.main', {
    url: 'main/:userID',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
.state('index.main.user', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        'user@index' : {
            templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
            controller: 'UserCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Parent Controller

```
$scope.showUser = function(user) {
    $state.go('index.main.user', { userID: user._id });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Naturally right after I posted this question I found the exact answer I was looking for.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316591/angularjs-ui-router-state-reload-child-state-only?lq=1) stackoverflow helped me alot.  I ended up using the following

```
$state.go('index.main.user', { userID: user._id }, {reload: 'index.main.user');
```