# force $state.reload with a start from state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states: `'home.person','home.person.house'`

I'm in 'home.person.house' and want to hard reload state stating from 'home.person'. According to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1809, I can pass as a parameter the start state from which the reload will start. So, I have the following line:

```
$state.reload('home.person');
```

However, the reload doesn't occur even thought everything in ui-route seems to work fine (debugged it). The resolve function of state 'home.person' wasn't called. Are there any suggestions why I'm not getting the result I wish for?

Comment: $state.reload('home.person');. don't need to specify route, $state.reload() enough. use $state.go('home.person'); for navigation

Comment: But that is not what I'm after. I want to stay in the current state, but need the reload to happen from my parent state, because data is changed in it, and that will cause a view change. As you can see in the pull request I added as a link, that's the behavior they added to support this functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316591/angularjs-ui-router-state-reload-child-state-only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165344/angularjs-angular-ui-router-reload-only-nested-view-not-parent

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pdu53I5uDvmkN1pZntli?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this : 
`$state.go("home.person",{reload:true});`
It would be good if you could share the parent and child state codes. It's difficult to provide a solution without much reference.